# How to resolve ajax call in if else condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Using an `if-else` condition trying to call an API using jQuery Ajax.

Not able to figure out why my ajax function is still called even though it's in else statement.

This is my code:

```
if (e.value == null || e.value == ""|| e.value.trim().length < 1) {
    // Alert is shown
    alert("title cannot be null");
} else {
    alert('else');
    // Still calling this ajax function
    $.ajax({
        data: {"bugid":bugid,"value":e.value,"colname":type},
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {   
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
    });
}
```

Comment: Control will go in else condition only when if fails!

Comment: i don't want that else part to execute when if condition is true... right now the ajax is running in both the cases

Comment: No issues with your code execerpt. It should work without issues. You would get alert becasue you have alert in your if as well as in else clause. what's the value of e.value when it goes into both if and else (which is impossible)?

Comment: Else part anyway wont get executed if 'if' condition is true.

Comment: yes the complication is every time if is true.. else also gets executed.. :( .. I tried to comment the ajax part and after that when if is true else was not executing. so i guess there is something wrong with ajax.. bcoz it is executing no matter what if else says

Answer (score 0):

this is the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. So you will have to make it synchronous forcefully, you have to create a separate function which will contain ajax call in itself. See below to make a function synchronous.

```
function foo(params, callback){
    // do stuff with params

    // move on to next step
    callback(params)
}

function bar(params, callback){
  // do stuff with params

  // move on to next step
  callback(params)
}

foo(1, bar);
```